# AngularJS Print Hidden Div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Recently a project has came around that I need to print a specific part of a page. Currently it is a dynamic accordion list that a user can expand and see results. The user has the option to print the contents of the expanded accordion, but only the one the the user has expanded.

My code of the accorddion is like this:

```
 <accordion>
  <accordion-group class="test" ng-repeat="item in ItemsPW">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
      Header Stuff
    </accordion-heading>
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 supply-item-print">
          <button class="btn-print btn-success" type="submit"
             ng-click="printDiv(item.line);">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           </button>
       </div>
    </div>
  </accordion-group>
 </accordion>
```

This could have zero or several items to expand. Currently I have a hidden `div` that uses AngularJS to hide some of the content. Each accordion section is different.

I have tried to print this two different ways:

**Code 1:**

```
var restorePage = document.body.innerHTML;
var printContent = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +  printContent  + "</body>";
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = restorePage;
```

This works, however, this code rewrites the page contents and when I click back on the page, it refreshes the whole page.

**Code 2**

```
var printContents = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').innerHTML;
var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1000,height=600');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link href="public/css/style.css" ' +
    'rel="stylesheet"></head><body>' + printContents + '</html>');
popupWin.document.close();
```

This doesn't work so well with AngularJS. When I open the new window only the static content is sent over. So the content that is suppose to be hidden in the `div` is not hidden.

**Goal**
Take the content of the hidden `div`, which uses AngularJS to hide content dynamically and print it.

**HiddenDiv**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Boxes</th>
    <th>Bags</th>
    <th>Supplies</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><span ng-hide="item.box1 == '0'">Box1</span></td>
    <td><span ng-hide="item.box2 == '0'">Box2</span></td>
    <td><span ng-hide="item.Bag1 == '0'">Bag1</span></td>
    <td><span ng-hide="item.tape == '0'">Tape</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The fields are hidden based on the values of the item, which will resemble what the accordion has.

Comment: Can you create a bin or fiddle please? I'm sure that once you did it you will get an answer in few minutes..

Comment: I will try to put this into a fiddle, but is there something that isn't clear? Code 1 writes a new page contents and call `window.print()` then when it is done, puts the original contents back on the page. But when this is done, when the user clicks back on the page, it refreshes. Code 2 gets the HTML of the hidden `div` and puts it into a new window. I suspect since it is a new window that there is no AngularJS involve so it doesn't know what to hide.

Comment: Do you want to hide, in the print, what the angular hide?

Comment: In the hiddenDiv there is a table, I am using `ng-hide` to hide the field that is not needed. For example, if you look at the section above, there are three columns, Boxes, Bags, Supplies, and a row with Box1, Box2, Bag1, Tape. Based on the request from the server, I will hide the fields that do not need those supplies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `style` tag with:

```
.ng-hide { display: none !important; }
```

**Full code:** (This work will not work in the snippet. To see the effect go the [bin](http://jsbin.com/tezane/edit?html,js))

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function(){

});

function printDiv() {
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1000,height=600');

  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link href="public/css/style.css" ' +
                          'rel="stylesheet"><style>.ng-hide { display: none !important; }</style></head><body>' + document.querySelector('#div').innerHTML + '</html>');

  setTimeout(function(){
    popupWin.print();  
    popupWin.close();  
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" id="div">
  Visible
  <div ng-hide="true">Text</div>
</div>

<button onclick="printDiv()">Print</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple thing, but had me stymied for so long!

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck!